# Hi.I am try to understand why when i call function add() return statement will execute multiply times and var counter=0; just one time?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I am try to understand why when i call function add() return statement will execute multiply times and var counter=0; just one time ?

```
document.body.onload=function(){

  var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
  })();

  add();
  add();
}
```

Comment: because var counter=0 is executed in the IIFE, which returns a function that increments counter

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What output do you expect? On the first call the function will return the result of `counter += 1`, which is 1. If you want 0 on the first call, consider `return counter++;`

Comment: At first I didn't understand the question, but now I think it's interesting. Firstly, `add` is a function created via an immediately invoking function. Inside that function is a variable called `counter` which the returned function `add` should have access to due to the idea of enclosure.  Therefore,  each time you call add, you should get the value of `counter + 1`, while no other function should be able to access `counter`.

Comment: I know this is IIFE function ,and i know it runs only once,but question is : If i call add(); two times return statement will be executed two times but counter =0 only one time,on first call . Why?

Comment: No. The return statement is only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code consists of three functions:

1. One function is invoked when body is loaded.

   ```
   function(){
     var add = ...;
     add();
     add();
   }
   ```
2. That function is defining and invoking an unnamed function for assigning its result to variable `add`. *Due to its lack of a name it can't be reinvoked later.*

   ```
   function () {
     var counter = 0;
     return ...
   }
   ```

   By wrapping this function in `(...)()` it is invoked instantly.
3. That anonymous function's result is another function assigned to `add` in context of first function. Thus, `add` is now referring to the following function object (which is identical to "being a function" in Javascript):

   ```
   function () {return counter += 1;}
   ```

It is important to see what function is invoked when. According to your excerpt

- first function is defined here to be invoked by browser.
- second function is invoked as part of invoked function #1.
- third function is defined w/o invocation first, but invoked later via its "name" `add`.

So, what is happening:

- The onload-function is invoked as expected.
- The defining function (function factory) in second step is invoked once to create a value for `add`.
- `add()` is using that function's result - the returned function with closure scope access to counter - instead of re-invoking that defining function.

You actually need to get the scopes of either execution right:

> I am try to understand why when i call function add() return statement will execute multiply times and var counter=0; just one time ?

The `return` at beginning of line following `var counter = 0;` is invoked only once, too. But the `return` inside function returned by that former `return` is invoked multiple times.